# Figure content way too large, overflows the page

Tags: floats, box

I want to have text and figures side by side, to do so, I managed to get this code:

```
\begin{figure}[]
\subsubsection{\large Helpmate}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt][c]{

        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.47\textwidth}
            Used in over 70 hospitals across US [11]. They are used to deliver medications, meals, X-rays, lab samples, supplies, equipment and patients records around the healthcare facility's departments. Has 6 ft$^{3} $ cargo space and 200 lb payload. Up to 12 hours of continuous operation. \par

            \vspace{0.4cm}
            \textbf{Mechanical and electronical}
            \vspace{0.4cm}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
                \item Infrared
                \item Forward and sideways sonar
                \item Touch-sensitive bumpers at the bottom
                \item Wheel encoders
                \item Ceiling-facing camera to extract orientation and position information from ceiling lights. [12]
                \item Two alternate structured light beams to detect objects in a 60 deg sweep in front of the robot. [12]
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{0.3cm}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{helpmate}
            \caption{HelpMate} \label{helpmate}
        \end{minipage}
    }


\subsubsection{\large Helpmate}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt][c]{

        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.47\textwidth}
            Used in over 70 hospitals across US [11]. They are used to deliver medications, meals, X-rays, lab samples, supplies, equipment and patients records around the healthcare facility's departments. Has 6 ft$^{3} $ cargo space and 200 lb payload. Up to 12 hours of continuous operation. \par

            \vspace{0.4cm}
            \textbf{Mechanical and electronical}
            \vspace{0.4cm}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
                \item Infrared
                \item Forward and sideways sonar
                \item Touch-sensitive bumpers at the bottom
                \item Wheel encoders
                \item Ceiling-facing camera to extract orientation and position information from ceiling lights. [12]
                \item Two alternate structured light beams to detect objects in a 60 deg sweep in front of the robot. [12]
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{0.3cm}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{helpmate}
            \caption{HelpMate} \label{helpmate}
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{figure}
```

But the problem is obvious in the image below, the content is overflowing the page height. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Would you please extend your code to an MWE? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Don't use `\subsubsection` inside a float

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the `wrapfig` package or at `insbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems like the text with its subsubsections belongs into the flow of your document and not in floats. Therefore I suggest to not wrap it in a figure environment, but simply place the minipages besides each other.

To create a caption for your image, you can use `\captionof` from the caption package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Helpmate}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.54\textwidth}
   Used in over 70 hospitals across US [11]. They are used to deliver medications, meals, X-rays, lab samples, supplies, equipment and patients records around the healthcare facility's departments. Has 6 ft$^{3} $ cargo space and 200 lb payload. Up to 12 hours of continuous operation.

   \bigskip
   \textbf{Mechanical and electronical}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Infrared
        \item Forward and sideways sonar
        \item Touch-sensitive bumpers at the bottom
        \item Wheel encoders
        \item Ceiling-facing camera to extract orientation and position information from ceiling lights. [12]
        \item Two alternate structured light beams to detect objects in a 60 deg sweep in front of the robot. [12]
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.44\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{HelpMate}
  \label{helpmate1}
\end{minipage}

\subsubsection{Helpmate}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.54\textwidth}
   Used in over 70 hospitals across US [11]. They are used to deliver medications, meals, X-rays, lab samples, supplies, equipment and patients records around the healthcare facility's departments. Has 6 ft$^{3} $ cargo space and 200 lb payload. Up to 12 hours of continuous operation.

   \bigskip
   \textbf{Mechanical and electronical}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Infrared
        \item Forward and sideways sonar
        \item Touch-sensitive bumpers at the bottom
        \item Wheel encoders
        \item Ceiling-facing camera to extract orientation and position information from ceiling lights. [12]
        \item Two alternate structured light beams to detect objects in a 60 deg sweep in front of the robot. [12]
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.44\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{HelpMate}
  \label{helpmate2}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @mclzc You're welcome! The trick is not to fight against latex, but to let latex create your document for you :)